# Detect memory leak in firefox addon-sdk based extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla, add-on

Is there some way to detect place of memory leak in firefox addon-sdk based extension? Some profiler?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Makyen, now its fixed.

Comment: Partially, but the question title does not reflect the contents of the question.